# Is it possible to add arbitrary keybindings to the Python interpreter?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, interpreter, key-bindings, python

In the python interpreter we can use

```
readline.parse_and_bind('tab: complete')
```

to enable tab completion

Is it possible to bind arbitrary keys to our own functions?
I'd like to bind CTRL+E and CTRL+SHIFT+E to edit_history() and edit_history(True) respectively, where edit_history() is my own function defined in .pythonrc

```
def edit_history(fork=False):
    import readline
    timeStamp = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
    tmpFile = '/tmp/pyHistory.%s' % timeStamp
    readline.write_history_file(tmpFile)
    if not fork:
        os.system('gvim -f %s' % tmpFile)
        readline.clear_history()
        readline.read_history_file(tmpFile)
        os.unlink(tmpFile)
    else:
        os.system('gvim %s' % tmpFile)
```

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated

Thanks,
Dado

Comment: You should look at enhanced interpreters like [iPython](http://ipython.org/), it has a lot of interesting `%magic`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Paulo, but I can't get used to iPython.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes... kind of. After defining your `edit_history` function, you can map a key to the sequence "edit_history()\n". Pressing that key would simulate typing "edit_history" followed by the Enter key.

Comment: Ah, I tried that without ()\n, since the binding for complete doesn't include that. But I'm not sure how to specify keys. Do you have an example for F2 or CTRL+E?
Thanks!

Comment: I managed to get it to work with
   readline.parse_and_bind('C-e: "edit_history()\n"')
Couldn't combine Meta or Shift with that.
I might need a completely separate binding.
Thank you chepner for pointing me in the right direction.